# Hibernate subclass query : Java.lang.object cannot be cast to, ERROR

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, casting

I have three Java Class, **A** which is the parent and **B & C** are subclasses of A. I have a Hibernate mapping file for A where I have mapped B & C using *joined-subclass*. Now when I try to query **C** I get **[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to  A**. The query that Hibernate generates is correct but why it is not allowing the casting to A?

I have tried the following queries, both result in the same error.

```
session.createQuery("from Request as req inner join req.category where req.class=Externalrequest and req.requestId=:id");

session.createQuery("from ExternalRequest as ereq inner join ereq.category where ereq.requestId=:id");
```

Where Request is the parent class and ExternalRequest & InternalRequest are the child class.

And here is the basic structure of my mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Request" table="request" schema="public">
    <id name="requestId" type="integer">
        <column name="request_id" />
        <generator class="sequence" >
            <param name="sequence">request_request_id_seq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>


    <many-to-one name="category" column="category"  class="RequestCategory" />


     <joined-subclass name="ExternalRequest" table="external_request">
            <key column="request_id"/>
            .........

     </joined-subclass>

      <joined-subclass name="InternalRequest" table="internal_request">
            <key column="request_id"/>
            .......
     </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

Comment: Can you share the query please?

Comment: Can you share the mapping file as well?

Comment: What type(class) of variable do you assign the result of the above to?

Comment: @Priyesh I have tried both Request & ExternalRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Ljava.lang.Object;`  is the string representation of an array of Objects.
I think what is happening is that you are trying to assign the result of the query, that is an array of `Request` or `ExternalRequest`, to a variable of class `Request` or `ExternalRequest`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, It is returning array of objects and I have added **fetch** now to get a single object, thanks.